# Solving root stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm concerned with the following SDE:
$$d Y_t= v \,dt + \sqrt {|Y_t|} \,d W_t$$
with $Y_0=-a$, $v>0$ being a constant, $a>0$ and $W_t$ as standard Brownian Motion. Do you have hints how to solve the SDE? Furthermore, I am interested in results (like density or moments) about the first hitting time of $a$ by the corresponding stochastic process.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about $v$ , is it a constant ? function ?

Comment: This is pretty close to the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross model for which the density and moments can be solved closed form (it also seems that your process stays always positive after it has reached a positive value). You could check if derivations for the CIR extend to your case somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Question asks for hints but given the 6+ years since asking I'm posting my attempt at a solution.

We first assume the existence of some function $F(W_t)=Y_t$ such that
\begin{equation}
dY_t = \frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t}dW_T + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial W_t^2}dt.
\end{equation}
From comparison with the given equation of the SDE, we find that

1. $\frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t}=\sqrt{|F(W_t)|}$
2. $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial W_t^2}=v$
3. $F(t=0)=-a$

Integrating 2. w.r.t. $W_t$, we find that $(\star)$ $\frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t}=vW_t + c_0$ where $c_0$ is some constant of integration. Integrating again and using $d(W_t^2)=2W_t dW_t + dt$, we find that
\begin{equation}
F(W_t)=\frac{v}{2}(W_t^2-t)+c_0 W_t + c_1,
\end{equation}
where $c_1$ is again a constant of integration.

Using the above with 3., we find $F(t=0)=c_1=-a$. Then, using 1. and $(\star)$ at $t=0$, we find that $c_0=\sqrt{|-a|}=\sqrt{a}$ since $a>0$.

Therefore, $Y_t$ is given by
\begin{equation}
Y_t=\frac{v}{2}(W_t^2-t)+\sqrt{a}W_t-a.
\end{equation}